# The linguistic origins of English suffixes

Tags: etymology

Many English words have Greek origins, eg an octopus has 8 legs and in Greek octo means 8.  Do English suffixes such as -able, -er and -ful also have Greek origins?

Comment: No. That's a short answer to a pretty broad question. If you can explain in more detail what kind of suffixes you're interested in, that would help. I can't tell if your question is more like "are there *any* English suffixes that come from Greek" or "what language(s) do the most common English suffixes come from"? You should also include some research of your own, which is easy to do using free online dictionaries with etymology/word origin sections.

Comment: Here's the Oxford Dictionaries entries for *[-able](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/-able), [-er](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/-er), [-ful](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/-ful)* (see the "Origin" sections). Here's the Wiktionary  entries for *[-able](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/-able#English), [-er](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/-er#English), [-ful](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/-ful#English)* (see the "Etymology" sections).

Answer (score 2):

A short answer to your question:

[Suffix:](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/suffix)

> - A morpheme added at the of a word to form a derivative (e.g. -ation, -fy, -ing, -itis).(ODO)
> - [The origin of suffixes](http://www.english-for-students.com/Suffixes.html) is the languages of Latin, Greek and English itself.

A reliable source for the etymology of words is  Etymonline:

[-able](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=-able&allowed_in_frame=0)
[-er](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=-er&allowed_in_frame=0)
[-ful](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=-ful&allowed_in_frame=0)